# How to echo out multiple lines of HTML Code?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, echo

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234');
mysql_select_db('database');

$query = "SELECT user_name FROM users";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<div class="mosaic-block bar2" onmouseout="decolorit2()" onmouseover="colorit2()">'
        '<a target="_blank" class="mosaic-overlay">'
            '<div class="details">'
                '<p class="font_us">' . $row['user_name'] . '</p>   <br/>'
                '<p class="font_us1">technische Umsetzung</p>'
            '</div>'
        '</a>'
        '<div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img id="pic" src="../views/pictures/pic"/></div>'
    '</div>';

}
mysql_close();

?>
```

So I wanted to output the usernames of my database with some javascript effect, but it doesn't show. How do I have to echo this out?

Comment: Don't use multi-line echoes. Use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) instead. Plus you're simply assuming that your DB operations have succeeded. Since you have absolutely no error handling, you will NEVER be able to tell if you're suffering from a bug, or there simply isn't any data to output in the first place.

Comment: @rullof: uh, why? OP's only ever outputting the username field anyways, so forcing the db to send the entire table across the wire is a waste.

Comment: you need to turn on php errors as this looks like invalid syntax. you'll need a . (period) after every line in your echo to concatenate all the strings. also, it doesn't look like you actually ran the query and defined what $result is.

Comment: You're also never running your `$query` SQL string. Where do you assume `$result` to come from?

Answer (score 4):

```
echo 'foo
      bar
      baz';
```

No need to close the quote on each newline. Better though, simply go out of PHP mode:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

<div>
    ...
       <?php echo $row['user_name']; ?>
    ...
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Even better yet for readability (IMO):

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>

    ...

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: yeah, but how can i go out of the while loop and enter it again? I don't know if you get what i mean! =)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pdo` or `mysqli`.
You did not concat   your string.

```
 <?php

    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234');
    mysql_select_db('database');

    $query = "SELECT user_name FROM users";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<div class="mosaic-block bar2" onmouseout="decolorit2()" onmouseover="colorit2()">'.
            '<a target="_blank" class="mosaic-overlay">'.
                '<div class="details">'.
                    '<p class="font_us">' . $row['user_name'] . '</p>   <br/>'.
                    '<p class="font_us1">technische Umsetzung</p>'.
                '</div>'.
            '</a>'.
            '<div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img id="pic" src="../views/pictures/pic"/></div>'.
        '</div>';

    }
    mysql_close();

    ?>
```